# qemu-system-sparc: shared memory between host and guest

Tags: memory, qemu, solaris, data-transfer

All,

I've been looking into passing things between a host's shared memory and guest OS's shared memory, and have come across [this link](http://liujunming.top/2021/11/30/QEMU-tutorial-Inter-VM-Shared-Memory-device/). I've been able to successfully reproduce the output shown at the link using a Ubuntu 20.04 VM and starting it with `qemu-system-x86_64`. I'm curious as to what the equivalent commands might be for `qemu-system-sparc` and a Solaris 8 guest.

I've tried the following command:

```
./qemu-system-sparc -M SS-5 -m 128 -bios ./ss5.bin -drive file=sol8.qcow2,bus=0,unit=0,media=disk -object memory-backend-file,size=16M,share=on,mem-path=/dev/shm/shm1,id=shm1 -device ivshmem-plain,memdev=shm1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x10,master=on
```

This fails for the following reason:

```
qemu-system-sparc: -device ivshmem-plain,memdev=shm1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x10,master=on: 'ivshmem-plain' is not a valid device model name
```

Is this desire of passing data with shared memory in `qemu-system-sparc` possible?

Comment: Why not just map folders between machines?  Much simpler.  I do this with VMware and Hyper-V

Comment: @John Right, but I'm wanting to pass things at the byte level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear this is not possible. *qemu-system-sparc* does not support PCI and the *ivshmem* devices are emulated as PCI devices. *qemu-system-sparc64* on the other hand *does* support PCI, however it may not fulfill the *MSI_NONBROKEN* condition in [hw/misc/Kconfig](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/fcb237e64f9d026c03d635579c7b288d0008a6e5/hw/misc/Kconfig#L64) (*LINUX* and *IVSHMEM* depend on the host, not the guest system):

```
config IVSHMEM_DEVICE
    bool
    default y if PCI_DEVICES
    depends on PCI && LINUX && IVSHMEM && MSI_NONBROKEN
```

I haven’t been able to find out conclusively what exactly sets `MSI_NONBROKEN` on x86/64, possibly some system peripheral.

You can quickly check for supported devices in your particular QEMU emulator like this:

```
qemu-system-sparc -device help
qemu-system-sparc64 -device help
```

You’ll see that the SPARC emulator supports… well, nothing. SPARC64 supports a little more by supporting PCI.

---

From what I see your best bet is to try and use a read-write shared virtual disk. Dunno how that would work in practice though. Maybe try it with a small RAW (not QCOW2 or the like) image file. The starting point is documented [here](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-block-drivers.html#disk-image-file-locking) (disabling locking etc), but I’m not sure how to go from there. You somehow need to add it as a SCSI virtual hard drive to your VM.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I had a feeling it might not be possible with `qemu-system-sparc`. Good to know there are alternatives, though.